# Shared resource and point of failure

Tags: iis, load-balancing, arr

We need to add the high availability feature in our web application so I am considering load balancing (Application Request Routing in IIS). Here is my setup: 
Server 01: This is where the ARR is installed with two nodes (02 and 03).
Server 02: This is the node 02 in Server 01.
Server 03: This is the node 03 in Server 01.

Assuming I have set it up correctly, question 1: I need to make sure that Server 01 is up all the time to archive the high availability feature. If I did not have ARR and host my web application directly on Server 01, I also need to make sure it is up all the time. What is the difference? 
question 2: I have a folder that my users will upload files to the web server. That folder is available on both Server 02 and 03. If a file is saved on 02 but the request for that file goes to 03, it will not be able to find it. How do I share the resources between 02 and 03?

Comment: for HA what you are using web farm or NLB configuration?

Comment: Web farm, we are looking to install the ARR extensions.

Comment: if you want to download arr extension you can download from this [link](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing). and refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-hosting/scenario-build-a-web-farm-with-iis-servers/overview-build-a-web-farm-with-iis-servers) for how to configure arr and web farm to achieve high availability in iis.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are only looking for **high availability**, we will host the web application on Server 01 and have a cluster (Server 02). So when Server 01 is down, Server 02 will take over. Regarding to sharing the resources (folder), we will have a designated File Server that both Server 01 and Server 02 will point to.